# "unrecognized options" while installing php

Tags: macos, mac, php, compile

I want to compile php 5.4.8 on my mac 10.8.2, but get some errors which cant solve by my self, so need your help.

Firstly i get default php options with `php -i | head`, after it do this command

> ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man
>   --infodir=/usr/share/info --disable-dependency-tracking --sysconfdir=/private/etc --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --enable-cli --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-libxml-dir=/usr --with-openssl=/usr --with-kerberos=/usr --with-zlib=/usr --enable-bcmath --with-bz2=/usr --enable-calendar --disable-cgi --with-curl=/usr --enable-dba --enable-ndbm=/usr --enable-exif --enable-fpm --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-79~4/Root/usr/local
>   --with-jpeg-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-79~4/Root/usr/local
>   --with-png-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-79~4/Root/usr/local
>   --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-icu-dir=/usr --with-iodbc=/usr --with-ldap=/usr --with-ldap-sasl=/usr --with-libedit=/usr --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --without-pear --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock --with-readline=/usr --enable-shmop --with-snmp=/usr --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sqlite-utf8 --enable-suhosin --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --with-tidy --enable-wddx --with-xmlrpc --with-iconv-dir=/usr --with-xsl=/usr --enable-zend-multibyte --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --with-pgsql=/usr --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr

But get this error

> config.status: creating Makefile config.status: creating jconfig.h
>   config.status: jconfig.h is unchanged config.status: executing
>   depfiles commands config.status: executing libtool commands configure:
>   WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-cli, --with-config-file-path,
>   --with-libxml-dir, --with-openssl, --with-kerberos, --with-zlib, --enable-bcmath, --with-bz2, --enable-calendar, --disable-cgi, --with-curl, --enable-dba, --enable-ndbm, --enable-exif, --enable-fpm, --enable-ftp, --with-gd, --with-freetype-dir, --with-jpeg-dir, --with-png-dir, --enable-gd-native-ttf, --with-icu-dir, --with-iodbc, --with-ldap, --with-ldap-sasl, --with-libedit, --enable-mbstring, --enable-mbregex, --with-mysql, --with-mysqli, --without-pear, --with-pdo-mysql, --with-mysql-sock, --with-readline, --enable-shmop, --with-snmp, --enable-soap, --enable-sockets, --enable-sqlite-utf8, --enable-suhosin, --enable-sysvmsg, --enable-sysvsem, --enable-sysvshm, --with-tidy, --enable-wddx, --with-xmlrpc, --with-iconv-dir, --with-xsl, --enable-zend-multibyte, --enable-zip, --with-pcre-regex, --with-pgsql, --with-pdo-pgsql

Maybe someone have some suggestions on this?

Comment: Is there even such commands : --enable-cli and so on? I don't thinkso. Where did you get all the commands from?

Comment: @superuser `php -i | head`